# Laravel Ajax Failed loading Post

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am trying to update data but i am getting error, failed loading post.

**AJAX code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {


    $('#update-data').on('click',function(){
alert("run");
    //  e.preventDefault(e);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "teachers/" + $('#update-data').attr("value"),
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {

    },
            success: function (data) {
                    alert("updated");
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**view:**

when i try all text field in div i get error failed loading post,

```
<div id="update-form">
      //all text fields
 <button type="button"name="id" value="{{@$teacher->id}}" id="update-data" >UPDATE</button> 
 </div>
```

but when i put everything in form my data is being updated correctly, but in this case ajax code is totally ignored and only last record is updating.

```
<form action="@if(isset($teacher)) {{route('teachers.update', $teacher->id)}} @else {{route('teachers.store')}}
            @endif" method="post" id="update-form" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<button type="submit" name="id" value="{{@$teacher->id}}" id="update-data" > UPDATE</button>    
</form>
```

**Console Error:**

```
app.js:10216 POST http://todolist.local/teachers/729 405 (Method Not Allowed)
app.js:10216 XHR failed loading: POST "http://todolist.local/teachers/729".
javascript?v=1567677915:4 XHR finished loading: GET "http://todolist.local/_debugbar/open?op=get&id=X15228e3cd6c2213f70bded7c0a69583b".
```

**Update Controller:**

```
public function update(TeacherRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $teacher = Teacher::find($id);
  if($teacher->save()){
                  return response()->json([
                        'status' => 'success',
                        'msg' => 'esecond has been updated'
                    ]);
                }
    }
```

**web.php:**

```
Route::get('/', 'TeachersController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('teachers', 'TeachersController');
```

Comment: (Method Not Allowed), are you using right request?

Comment: Make sure that you have created `Post` route for your method

Comment: when i update using form, data is updating but only last record.

Comment: whats in your controller, are you doing conditional update?

Comment: i have added controller code in my question. it is only updating.

Comment: I suppose you should be calling `$('#myform').on('submit', ....)` instead of onClick on the button because `$(this).serialize()` expects a form, isn't it?
And secondly, isn't it that you need method spoofing to update a content i.e `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`?

Comment: if i add form tag, when i click on submit button, my ajax code is being ignored like it is not there.

Comment: check what request is sent by browser to server.

Comment: Please show your route (`web.php`).

Comment: i added web.php in question.

Comment: the issue occurs because of your page reload when you click on the form submit button.

Comment: @Fayakon I have posted an answer. try and tell me any issue occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your ajax request as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {


    $('#update-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
           /*Your logic*/
        });
    });
});
```

View

```
<form action="@if(isset($teacher)) {{route('teachers.update', $teacher->id)}} @else {{route('teachers.store')}} @endif" method="post" id="update-form" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

 {{method_field('PUT')}}
 {{ csrf_field() }}

<button type="submit" name="id" value="{{@$teacher->id}}" id="update-data" > UPDATE</button>

</form>
```

Try this..
ajax post caused the webpage to reload before I could get a result, therefore.

Comment: i added form tag and used your ajax code, again only last record is updating.

Comment: if i edit any record from database, it is replacing last record id.

Comment: form action is also passing id, how to change that?

Comment: update button is changing id, but this stays same, <form action="@if(isset($teacher)) {{route('teachers.update', $teacher->id)}}